# Error Element type is invalid: forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to create a budget app in react on codesandbox. But I am having trouble with ReactDom.render... I don't know if I am importing the wrong stuff or not exporting correctly. The error I am getting is (Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `App`.)

here is the index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import App from "./App";

ReactDom.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);

export default App;


Here is App.js:

import Button from "react-bootstrap";
import Stack from "react-bootstrap";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import BudgetCard from "react-bootstrap";

function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Stack direction="horizontal" gap="2" className="mb-4">
        <h1 className="me-auto">Budgets</h1>
        <Button variant="primary">Add Budget</Button>
        <Button variant="outline-primary">Add Expense</Button>
        <Button variant="outline-primary">Save</Button>
      </Stack>
      <div
        style={{
          display: "grid",
          gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(auto-fil, minmax(300px, 1fr))",
          gap: "1rem",
          alignItems: "flex-start"
        }}
      >
        <BudgetCard></BudgetCard>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default App;

Here is my index.html:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>


Here is my Package.json:

{
  "name": "react",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "React example starter project",
  "keywords": [
    "react",
    "starter"
  ],
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "5.1.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "2.2.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "redux": "4.1.2",
    "uuid": "8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "7.13.8",
    "typescript": "4.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}

  


[Here is a screenshot of my setup][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcHwK.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the script runs before the div with an id of root is in the dom. Just invert the order in the html.

```
   <div id="root"></div>
   <script src="index.js"></script>
```

You can also add type="module" to your script.

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! I changed the order of the div and script. I am still getting the error. {"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function ( for composite components ). you likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `App`."}

Comment: Can you add your setup and package.json file? Are you importing React on the top of your App.js ?

Comment: I added my set up on codesandbox and my package.json file. I also posted a screenshot of codesandbox!